# refire collection.fetch in backbone.js using the same success and error callbacks

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a basic collection that does a fetch on document ready: ie:

```
message_list.fetch({

            success: function(){
                console.log('success');
                //render
                grid_view.render();
            },
            error: function(xhr, text, ajax){
                //set a column limit and retru
                console.log('retrying');
                urlParams.colLimit = true;
                $.ajax(this);
                return;
            },
            data: urlParams,
            processData:true
        });
```

This grabs a json from the server, which is querying an hbase table with thrift. With certain accounts the dataset in hbase is too large and it runs out of memory and returns a 500 response.  So I want to refire the same ajax call on error after I add a new query param. Looking at the jquery .ajax documentation it says to call $.ajax(this), but this is the window object.  Also the xhr variable has empty success function.  How do I refire the same ajax call with the same properties and success/error functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy -- make an object that you store and can pass back in:

```
var success_cb = function(){
    console.log('success');
    //render
    grid_view.render();
};

var error_cb = function(xhr, text, ajax){
    //set a column limit and retru
    console.log('retrying');
    urlParams.colLimit = true;
    $.ajax(this);
    return;
};

var fetch_options = {
        success: success_cb, 
        error: error_cb,
        data: urlParams,
        processData:true
}

message_list.fetch(fetch_options);
```

As long as the `fetch_options` is defined in the same scope as the two callback functions, and `fetch_options` is accessible outside of that scope, anything that can access `fetch_options` can use it as it's arguments to `.fetch`.

Comment: I set it up like this, and when it refires on error this is still the window object.  `var error_cb = function(xhr, response, text){ console.log(this); $.ajax(this);}` this logs the window object and refires to the pages url not the collection url `Window
Infinity: Infinity
$LAB: Object
$: function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
Array: function Array() { [native code] }
ArrayBuffer: function ArrayBuffer() { [native code] }
Attr: function Attr() { [native code] }
Audio: [object Function]
AudioProcessingEvent: function AudioProcessingEvent() { [native code] }.....

Comment: you need to bind `error_cb` to the context in which you want it to operate

Comment: I want error_cb to operate with the collection.fetch context? Is that what you mean? How do I bind this properly.

Comment: What do you want `this` to be when you log it?  Do you watn it to be the context where you're calling fetch from?  You do you want it to be somewhere else?  If you're in a view and you want the success/error callbacks to operate within the context of that view, you'll need to bind those callbacks to the current value of "this" inside your view.  i.e: `_.bind(success_cb, this)` and `_.bind(error_cb, this)`. You might want to read up on JavaScript closures -- it can be tricky to wrap your mind around sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

use Function.bind to bind the callbacks to the context you want: success_cb.bind(desired_context)
Function.bind is ECMAScript 5 so you may need to add a shim for it. A similar option is to use $.proxy: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: `bind` doesn't exist in a lot of browsers -- like Safari (at least it didn't in the most recent version of Safari from December 2011).  He is already using Backbone, so he's got Underscore installed, `_.bind` is a polyfilled method that uses the native bind if available, but also provides `bind` to older browsers as well.

Comment: So the first thing I want to do, before a view is rendered or defined, is to fetch the collection from a url, if that ajax call gets a 500 error I want to refire the ajax call but with a new Get param.  So the context is with the collection, so can I add `_bind(success_cb, this)` in the collection's init function?